# Horizontal lines on Dell Inspiron 15

Tags: display, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, lcd

so my laptop screen started showing a tiny line at the top left corner of the screen it was nothing at the moment and then after a month suddenly the whole screen was filled with colorful horizontal lines and disappeared after a day and half and everything started working fine and then after a week or so the whole screen became filled again and it won't go away when you are doing a regular thing on the laptop but when i open up a game(FarCry New Dawn) the screen starts working fine no lines at all and once you close the game the lines start showing up. and also there seems to be no problem on the startup screen just when the laptop actually boots up. also the horizontal lines are also not consistent their shape and place seems to change when you navigate between screen and folders.
[screen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lBWs.jpg)
Specs:
Intel core i7 7th gen
Nvidia 1050 4GB
Dell inspiron 15-5577

Comment: Dual graphics? Looks like either the Intel drivers are iffy or the Intel GPU is failing. Try drivers - https://downloadcenter.intel.com - & test the last few releases, just in case one's not behaving. That the taskbar looks clean makes me think drivers rather than hardware. You could also try manually flipping which GPU is running at any given time & see if that correlates.

Comment: what about the screen going back to normal when you open up a game?....i am thinking the Nvidia graphics card kicks in when you open up a game maybe...

Comment: the taskbar is also not clean it just happens to be that way on the picture...could it be a hardware problem? if it were why would it work when you open a game...

Comment: If it was a hardware problem, the first suspect would be the Intel GPU - which, as it is integral to the i7 would probably be cheaper to buy a new computer… This is why I suggested the course of action above, to see if you can eliminate that as the cause. Please test & add the details to your quesion.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds - and looks - like a defective graphics card (or perhaps broken driver). The reason it works on boot is because the 3D part of the graphics card isn't active yet. Try uninstalling your graphics card driver and reinstall it after rebooting and see if that produces any different result.